# Disabled button is clickable in ie 9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, browser, struts2-jquery

The button is given to be disabled. but it is still clickable in ie 9.

Working fine in ie 7.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#deleteclientajaxformlink').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

What can be the issue??? Any ways to disable from clicking?

struts2:

```
<sj:a id="deleteclientajaxformlink" formIds="deleteclientform"
targets="deleteclientformResult" button="true"
indicator="deleteclientsubmitindicator">Delete</sj:a>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#deleteclientajaxformlink').prop('disabled', true);`?

Comment: Also can try `$('#deleteclientajaxformlink').prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: That is not working.. its not disabling my button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery < 1.6,
do this:

```
  $('#deleteclientajaxformlink').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

If you are using jQuery 1.6+:

```
  $('#deleteclientajaxformlink').prop("disabled", true);
```

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for references "why".

Comment: Hey the lines you gave is working fine disabling it... but I am able to click it :( and hence the form is getting submitted in ie 9.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `<sj:a>` tag `disabled` attribute

```
   <sj:a id="deleteclientajaxformlink" formIds="deleteclientform"
    targets="deleteclientformResult" button="true"
    indicator="deleteclientsubmitindicator" disabled="true">Delete</sj:a>
```

https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AnchorTag

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the state of the button in the form submit event:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    if ($('#deleteclientajaxformlink').prop('disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above solutions, but they don't work. And here is my solution:

```
$('#deleteclientajaxformlink').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

Comment: While it's great that you've provided an alternate solution to the problem at hand, keep in mind that this question already had an accepted answer more than 2 years ago, so try to avoid reviving dead questions unless there is a notably better way of tackling the problem raised :)

Comment: But the accepted answer doesn't work, so I think my solution maybe useful for somebody else.